# Find the inverse of defined operation $\Delta$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry, inverse

We defined the operation $ \Delta $ as

$ (a,b) \Delta (c,d) = (ac + \delta bd, ad + bc) $ where $ a, b, c ,d \in \mathbb{Q} $

I have already proven that this operation is both commutative and associative.

I have also found it's identity element which is $ (1,0) $.

I am now asked to find it's inverse.

How would I approach this? Thanks !

Comment: I wish I was as smart as you Helen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the inverse in a vector space,by definition,this means:

$ (a,b) \Delta (c,d) = (ac + \delta bd, ad + bc)=(1,0)$ where $ a, b, c ,d \in \mathbb{Q} $

So : 
   $ac + \delta bd = 1 $
   $ad + bc = 0$

We have to solve for c and d in the system. So solve the system. You should be able to do the rest yourself now.

Comment: Hmmm... that is exactly what I did, but I seemed to be getting a really awkward answer. OK, back to the refill pad to try again !

Comment: Isn't it (1,0) not (0,1) ?

Comment: Oopsie,my bad.Fixed it.

Comment: I made the same mistake in the post, sorry ! (1,0) it is.

Comment: @JohnDoe Uh,where's my +1?